# android proper app distribution using gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, firebase-app-distribution

I am trying to create a gradle script to share apk with testers using the code below.

```
ext {
    TESTERS_LIST = ""
}
task uploadToFirebase(type: GradleBuild) {
    /*
        some logic here
    */
    tasks = ['appDistributionUploadBeta', 'app:assembleBeta']
}

task sendBuildToTeam1Qa() {
    TESTERS_LIST = "john@gmail.com, jane@gmail.com"
}
task sendBuildToTeam2Qa() {
    TESTERS_LIST = "other@gmail.com, another@gmail.com"
}
task sendBuildToTeam3Qa() {
    TESTERS_LIST = "doe@gmail.com"
}

sendBuildToTeam1Qa.dependsOn uploadToFirebase
sendBuildToTeam2Qa.dependsOn uploadToFirebase
sendBuildToTeam3Qa.dependsOn uploadToFirebase
```

and

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
     releaseNotes = project.RELEASE_NOTES_FROM_BRANCH
     testers = project.TESTERS_LIST
}
```

when I want to share apk with for example team1, I just run `"./gradlew sendBuildToTeam1Qa"`, but problem here is when I do that, because all other tasks also run in configuration phase, value of `TESTERS_LIST` becomes the latest task on gradle ( for example here value will be third task's tester's list, because that is the one that executed last in configuration phase)

I've tried wrapping `TESTERS_LIST` assignments with `doLast`, but when I do that at the end `TESTERS_LIST` becomes empty because it is executed after upload task to firebase